# Creating roll rate matrix from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

apologies if I am asking a very basic question. I want to replicate a simple roll matrix in python however I am struggling and I was wondering if I can get some help.

Ageing ( already imported as DF)

| Month | NYD | DPD30 | DPD60 | DPD90 | DPD120 | DPD150 | Loss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 1000 | 500 | 400 | 300 | 200 | 100 | 50 |
| Feb | 1200 | 400 | 350 | 250 | 150 | 180 | 30 |
| Mar | 900 | 890 | 250 | 200 | 180 | 120 | 100 |
| Apr | 2100 | 600 | 650 | 190 | 125 | 150 | 80 |
| May | 1800 | 1200 | 400 | 450 | 125 | 80 | 90 |
| June | 1500 | 900 | 800 | 257 | 325 | 90 | 75 |

Flow rate Matrix

| Month | NYD | DPD30 | DPD60 | DPD90 | DPD120 | DPD150 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Feb | 40% | 70% | 63% | 50% | 90% | 30% |
| Mar | 74% | 63% | 57% | 72% | 80% | 56% |
| Apr | 67% | 73% | 76% | 63% | 83% | 67% |
| May | 57% | 67% | 69% | 66% | 64% | 60% |
| June | 50% | 67% | 64% | 72% | 72% | 94% |

you can see from the above example, I have created a flow rate matrix from the ageing table. for example, 40% in Feb is calculated by dividing 400 in DPD30 divided by 1000 in NYD Jan (400/1000) (i.e 400 out 1000 moved into next bucket in the following month).

I would appreciate if someone can guide me on how I can recreate this in python. I have already imported CSV aging file as a df however I am not sure how to manipulate data in the df to create a new df for the flow rate matrix.

many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: 1. Please make the effort and do not paste images but add the data to the question.
2. The numbers are not following your description. Please ensure that you calculate the example the same way you describe.

Comment: edited. i hope it's clear now

Comment: It is definitely better. Thanks. A formula for calculating the values would help as it is still not clear to me how the next percentage values were calculated.

Comment: We are calculating how much outstanding amount flows into the next bucket. for example, we have 1,000 outstanding in Jan under NYD (not yet due) when it flows into Feb under DPD 30 remaining outstanding is 400 which means 40% of outstanding in jan remain outstanding in feb. Let me know if it's clear otherwise i will add cell references to reproduce exatc excel formula

Comment: You just repeated what is in the question. No, this is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


df=pd.read_excel(r"D:\Stack_overflow/test1.xlsx")


#TAKING OUT ALL THE COLUMNS WITH HAVING INT TYPE
cols=df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).columns
cols=cols.to_list()


#CREATING ANOTHER LIST WITH _tmp ADDED TO THE LIST ELEMNETS
cols2=[x + '_tmp' for x in cols]

cols2=cols2+['tmp']

cols=cols+['tmp']
print(cols2)

#ADDING TMP COLUMN TO DF
df['tmp']=0

df['Month']=df['Month'].shift(-1)

#RUNNING OUT THE LOOP FOR EVERY EELEMENT STARTING FROM THE DPD30 (ELEMENT 2nd of cols)
for i in range(len(cols)-1):
    df[cols[i]]=((df[cols[i+1]].shift(-1))/df[cols[i]])*100
    
print(df.head())

  Month        NYD      DPD30      DPD60  ...     DPD120     DPD150  Loss  tmp

    0   Feb  40.000000  70.000000  62.500000  ...  90.000000  30.000000   0.0    0
    1   Mar  74.166667  62.500000  57.142857  ...  80.000000  55.555556   0.0    0
    2   Apr  66.666667  73.033708  76.000000  ...  83.333333  66.666667   0.0    0
    3   May  57.142857  66.666667  69.230769  ...  64.000000  60.000000   0.0    0
    4  June  50.000000  66.666667  64.250000  ...  72.000000  93.750000   0.0    0
```

Later on you can drop the tmp column if not required or gives any error in further codes.

Hope that solves the problem.